# strikethrough characters on php stream output

Tags: php, linux, apache, stream, strikethrough

I am using php ssh2_exec to execute a ps aux command on a remote Linux server... The server initiating the connection is Ubuntu 14.04 and the server I am communicating with is Centos 6.6.

Both systems are fully updates and I am using the following versions of PHP and Apache on the Ubuntu system:

apache2                              2.4.7-1ubuntu4.5
libapache2-mod-php5                  5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.11

php5                                 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.11

I am using the following code to send the command and capture the stream:

```
echo '<pre>';
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
while($line = fgets($stream_out)) {
           flush();
           echo $line."<br />";
       }
echo '</pre>';
echo '<br />';
unset($connection);
```

$command is defined as: $command = "ps aux |sed '/[.*]/d'";

The command runs, but the returned text, while showing the processes running on the remote system, is stricken through text... Below is a link to an image of what is happening.

https://www.joeman1.com/images/stikethoughtest.png

(I would have posted the image, but Im new around here and need some reputation ;)).

This does not happen when I use php -f on the command line, just in a browser - IE, Firefox, and Chrome was tested.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? If you need more information, please let me know.

Thanks!
Joe

Comment: I would advise you review the page source and look at the resulting HTML. You may also want to look at your CSS, if any, and see if `pre {}` is being styled.

Comment: Hi Twisty :) - Ok, you got me to look at the HTML code on my browser, and for some reason, the echo $line was spitting out a couple of <s...> tags... So, I put echo "</s>" before the echo $line and it works now... I am not using any CSS, just php... Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking your HTML Source. Or:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
while($line = fgets($stream_out)) {
           flush();
           // convert the string to HTML Entities
           // Since you're getting data from a stream, no telling what might come out.
           echo htmlentities($line)."<br />";
       }
echo '</pre>';
echo '<br />';
unset($connection);
?>
```

Comment: Hi again Twisty :) - Ok I will try adding htmlentities and see how that works. I have to wait till I get to work tomorrow, then I will report back. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks Twisty! echo htmlentities($line)."<br />"; worked like a charm... You Rock!